# Show that 3 points are collinear

Tags: geometry, triangles

I'm struggling to solve this problem geometrically,I solved it with coordinates and now Im trying to prove it geometrically,but i came to no conclusion.

In an equilateral triangle we have the orthocentrum(O) and we choose a random point(M),then from that point we draw perpendiculars to each side of the triangle.The points that these perpendiculars meet with the triangle will make a new triangle lets say EFD.In this new EFD triangle we will have a new point (G) that is the centroid of triangle EFD.I need to show that M,G and O are collinear.
Here is the figure to this problem that I did in Geogebra.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Go online and buy a used copy of E.A. Maxwell's excellent book $The Methods of Plane Geometry based on the use of General Homogeneous Coordinates$  pub. Cambridge U.P.You will find a very good treatment of what hapens to such affine concepts as 'perpendicular', 'midpoint',etc. when the affine plane is embedded into the projective plane. Maxwell is particularly strong on expressing the classical geometry of the trianle in a projective, algebraic context.

Comment: You have added that you have solved it analytically. Can you say briefly how ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution which can be considered geometric on one hand but as well analytical on the other hand.

Knowing [Viviani's theorem](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/3004415840629.pdf.bannered.pdf), we can assume WLOG that equilateral triangle $ABC$ has sides such that the sum of distances to the (constant) sum of the sides is equal to $1$.

I assume you know *barycentric coordinates* (or *trilinear coordinates* which are the same for such a reference triangle).

I will take notation "b.c." for "barycentric coordinates".

I will use notations $A'B'C'$ for the so-called [**pedal triangle**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PedalTriangle.html) associated with $M$ (instead of $DEF$ in order to have a better homogeneity) ; see below:

[image]

Animated version [here](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/kgxxya7b) : you can move point $M$.

On this figure, if the b.c. of $M$ are $(a,b,c)$ with normalization:

$$a+b+c=1\tag{1}$$

then, in particular, the b.c. of the foot $A'$ of the perpendicular issued from $M$ onto $BC$ are:

$$A'(0,\ \ \underbrace{b+\tfrac12 a, \ \ c+\tfrac12 a}_{\text{see fig.}})\tag{2}$$

where the term $\tfrac12 a$ comes from the fact that we have two right triangles which are "half of equilateral triangles" with side $a$.

For similar reasons, the b.c. of $B'$ and $C'$ are:

$$B'(a+\tfrac12 b, \ \ 0, \ \ c+\tfrac12 b) \ \text{and} \ C'(a+\tfrac12 c, \ \ b+\tfrac12 c, \ \ 0)\tag{3}$$

Therefore, centroid $G$ of $A'B'C'$ has the following b.c., using (2) and (3) :

$$G(\tfrac13(2a+\tfrac{b+c}{2}), \ \ \tfrac13(2b+\tfrac{a+c}{2}), \ \ \tfrac13(2c+\tfrac{a+b}{2}))\tag{4}$$

Using (1), we can transform the b.c. in (4) into

$$G \left(\frac{3a+1}{6}, \ \ \frac{3b+1}{6}, \ \ \frac{3c+1}{6}\right)$$

2. The b.c. of $G$ being the half-sum of the b.c. of $M$ and $O$, we can conclude that **$G$ is the midpoint of $M$ and $O$**.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but in the end I succeeded in proving it using vectors too.

Comment: Were barycentric coordinates familiar to you ?

Comment: No they weren't so thank you for exposing me to this subject as well.

Comment: You have maybe seen that I have written now a complete answer. Besides, I would be interested by having some clues about your "full vector" solution.

Comment: I will type it down tomorrow when I have time,also I asked one of my proffesors about other possible proofs and he showed  me how to solve it using complex numbers too.I could also type that down if you are interested.

Comment: I would be interested by the first one. Thank you. I don't want you to loose time for the second solution with complex numbers : I have a good idea of how to use them in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

As the asked analytical proof was not included on time, a possible proof is left for the interested reader.

Calling

$$
\cases{
A = (0,0)\\
B = l(\cos\frac{\pi}{3},\sin\frac{\pi}{3})\\
C = l(1,0)
}
$$

the orthocentrum $O$ located at

$$
O = \frac 13(A+B+C) = l\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3}}\right)
$$

Now giving $M =(x,y)$ inside $\Delta ABC$, the $M$ projections onto the triangle sides are given by

$$
p_{AB}=A+\left((M-A)\cdot\hat v_{AB}\right)\hat v_{AB}
$$

where $\hat v_{AB}$ is the unitary vector in  $B-A$ direction. Analogously we have

$$
\cases{
p_{BC}=B+\left((M-B)\cdot\hat v_{BC}\right)\hat v_{BC}\\
p_{CA}=C+\left((M-C)\cdot\hat v_{CA}\right)\hat v_{CA}
}
$$

and

$$
G = \frac 13\left(p_{AB}+p_{BC}+p_{CA}\right)
$$

now as

$$
\cases{
\hat v_{AB} = \left(-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\\
\hat v_{BC} = (1,0)\\
\hat v_{CA} = \left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)
}
$$

we have

$$
G = \left(\frac{l}{4}+\frac{x}{2},\frac{l}{4 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{y}{2}\right)=\frac 12(O+M)
$$

hence $M, G, O$ are aligned.